# how do I call git commands without 'git ' in front?

Tags: zsh, git, command

How do I tell my zsh to automatically try a command with `git` in front, if the command is not found? E.g. I want to run `$ status` and if there is no `status` in `$PATH`, my zsh should try `git status`.

Comment: Have you considered making shell aliases for this? It's not really what you describe, but it would get the job done IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds fragile — you could get into the habit into typing `foo` instead of `git foo`, and then one day a new `foo` command appears and `foo` no longer invokes `git foo` — but it can be done. When a command is not found with normal lookup (alias, function, builtin, executable on `PATH`), [zsh invokes the `command_not_found_handler` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#Command-Execution) (if it's defined). This function receives the command and the command's arguments as its arguments.

```
command_not_found_handler () {
  git "$@"
}
```

If you want to do some fancier filtering, the command is in `$1` and its arguments can be referred to as `"$@[2,$#]"`.

```
command_not_found_handler () {
  if …; then
    git "$1" "$@[2,$#]"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Or `"$@[2,-1]"` instead of `"$@[2,$#]"`. Note that `"$1" "$@[2,$#]"` is `"$@"`.

Comment: Very fragile: `git rm` vs `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that do not creat problems for yourself, just checkout [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), and put

```
plugins=(git)
```

in your *.zshrc*, then you can see **git status** by typing **gst**.

...and a lot of others, checkout [git.plugin.zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh)